# implementing a generic method with varargs

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, variadic-functions

In my code, it appears convenient to use varargs when implementing a generic method when the type is an array:

```
public interface Codec<D,E> {
  E encode(D decoded);
  D decode(E encoded);
}

public class MyCodec implements Codec<byte[], char[]> {
  @Override char[] encode(byte... decoded) {...}
  @Override byte[] decode(char... encoded) {...}
}
```

When I write this, Eclipse shows a warning:

> Varargs methods should only override or be overridden by other varargs
>   methods unlike MyCodec.encode(byte...)     and
>   Codec.encode(byte[])

Should I just ignore the warning, or is this going to cause some unforeseen problems?

Comment: What's Eclipse's quick fix? Is there a `SuppressWarnings("varargs")` or similar? (just curious)

Comment: Could it be that the warning is in case some day the method signatures are not considered equivalent? Odd...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an Eclipse-specific warning. It has nothing to do with generics specifically and can be reproduced with this example:

```
class A {
    m(int[] ints) { }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    m(int... ints) { }
}
```

As the other answers point out, varargs are purely a compile-time feature and there's no difference at runtime. I tried searching for the specific reasoning behind the warning but couldn't turn anything up. Likely it's considered bad practice to alternate method overrides between varargs and non-varargs because it's confusing and arbitrary. But this is *in general* - your use case seems more reasonable as long as callers are always going to be using a statically-typed `MyCodec` instead of coding to interface with a `Codec<byte[], char[]>`.

Unfortunately there is no way to suppress this warning - even `@SuppressWarnings("all")` won't make it yield. Which is unfortunate considering how obscure of a warning it is. Here's an ancient conversation about this same issue: http://echelog.com/logs/browse/eclipse/1196982000 (scroll to 20:45:02) - proving it's bit people long before you. Seems like an Eclipse bug that it can't be suppressed.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote two test files. Here's the first:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

And here's the second:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

(The only difference between these two files is the `String[] args` vs `String... args`.)

Then, I ran `javap -c` on each file to see the disassembly. The contents of the `main` method were identical:

```
Code:
   0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3: aload_0       
   4: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/util/Arrays.toString:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
   7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  10: return
```

The only difference was the method header, which was simply the method signature of each method:

- `public static void main(java.lang.String[]);`
- `public static void main(java.lang.String...);`

With this in mind, I would say that it's a safe assumption that nothing bad will happen.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but just because both examples compile into the same bytecode doesn't mean the warning is meaningless. Generic and non-generic code compiles into the same byte-code for example.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *bytecode*, no problem.

```
public byte[] encode(char...);
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_VARARGS

  LineNumberTable:
    line 4: 0
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           0       2     0  this   LMyEncoder;
           0       2     1  args   [C          // char[]
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
       0: aconst_null   
       1: areturn                              // return null;
    LineNumberTable:
      line 4: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
             0       2     0  this   LMyEncoder;
             0       2     1  args   [C

public java.lang.Object encode(java.lang.Object);
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_VARARGS, ACC_SYNTHETIC

  LineNumberTable:
    line 1: 0
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
       0: aload_0       
       1: aload_1       
       2: checkcast     #27          // class "[C"            -> char[]
       5: invokevirtual #28          // Method encode:([C)[B  -> return byte[]
       8: areturn       
    LineNumberTable:
      line 1: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
```

If you make a call using one reference of the interface, the method with the flag [`ACC_BRIDGE`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/util/IModifierConstants.html#ACC_BRIDGE) check ([`checkcast`](http://www.vmth.ucdavis.edu/incoming/Jasmin/ref--7.html)) if the type of the argument is the same as is defined in the type parameter (`java.lang.ClassCastException` otherwise, but will never happen if you allways provides the [*type parameter*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)), then run the method implementation.

In another hand, if you compile this with javac, none warning is show.